# Instance variable lifetime in classes vs structs

Tags: c#, .net

I know that an instance variable of a class comes to life when a new instance of that class is instantiated and when there are no references to that instance, the instance's destructor has executed. But what about instance variables lifetime in structs?

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691165(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Just a reminder that they're called finalizers in C#, not destructors.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer The C# specification refers to them as destructors (section §1.6.7.6).

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Confusingly they're really called destructors (even if they're technically finalizers).

Comment: OK now I'm confused! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and when there are no references to that instance, the instance's destructor has executed

Only *if* that class has a destructor (otherwise, its memory is simply reclaimed), *if* `GC.SuppressFinalize` hasn't been called on that object, and *when* the Garbage Collector decides to collect the generation to which that object belongs.

Also note that destroying an object isn't the same as reclaiming its memory.
When the GC calls an object's destructor, the object will be promoted to the next generation, and its memory will only be reclaimed the next time the GC decides to collect *that* generation, *if there are still no strong references to it*.

And this is why it's possible (but don't do it!) to *resurrect* an object, by creating a strong reference to itself (e.g., assigning itself to a static field) *within* the destructor.

> But what about instance variables lifetime in structs?

If they're declared within a method and not *leaked* anywhere (such as using it in a closure, or being assigned to a field member), chances are they'll be put on the stack and deleted deterministically when the method ends, and the GC will never know about it.

If they're assigned to a field, they'll live as long as the enclosing class lives.

Also, structs can't have destructors.

Comment: You could also add *and when the Garbage Collector was not told explicitly to suppress this finalizer* for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not true, that if there are no references to the instance, it's destructor is being called. What really happens is that at the time of Garbage Collector's choice the object is marked as garbage and then later, again at the time of Garbage Collector's choice the object is destroyed.

In case of structures, you have to remember, that structure behaves similarly as any other value-type object (such as int, float and so on). So, for example, if you keep structure in a local variable and exit the method, structure is deleted from the stack, thus clearing all references to its all fields - and if they are reference-typed (and no other references exists), they will be collected by the GC in the same manner I described earlier. If they are value-typed, they are deleted immediately.

You can read more about this matter in [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/5-tips-and-techniques-for-avoiding-automatic-gc-collections/) and on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691165%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read up on [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as the assumptions you make are outright wrong. When nothing references an object, GC *may* collect it, but you won't know precisely when. Also, C# has no destructors, it has [*finalizers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer), which aren't deterministic as opposed to destructors. The syntax is the same as the C++ destructor, but under the hood they're different.

The difference between reference types (classes) and value types (structs), is that reference types are garbage collected if there is no valid reference to them anymore, where value types are collected when they go out of scope. Types like `int`, `IntPtr`, etc are all structs and follow the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN:

"An instance variable of a struct has exactly the same lifetime as the struct variable to which it belongs i.e, when a variable of a struct type comes into existence or ceases to exist, so too do the instance variables of the struct."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691165(v=vs.71).aspx

(Although it is destroyed by the Garbage Collector actually).